# Unix find command help

Tags: unix, shell, ksh

Hi can anybody help me with the following line;

```
find . \( -type d ! -name . -prune \) -o -type f -name "*Log*"
```

Basically it should find directories where files with "Log" in their name are present.

I have a structure like this:

```
/logs
  |
  |
  ----folder1
  |       |
  |       |
  |       ---App1LogDate.txt
  |
  ----folder2
  |      |
  |      |
  |      ---App2LogDate.txt
  |
  |
  |--App3LogDate.txt
  |
  |--App4LogDate.txt
```

So given that I will run this line within /logs directory I should get the following results:

```
.
./folder1
./folder2
```

3 directories in total.

Comment: did you mean to say `-type d` instead of `-type f` in the "or" portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly left-field, but based on the above description, the following should do exactly what you want:

```
find . -type f -name "*Log*" -print | sed -E 's/\/[^\/]+$//' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: ahh, we have ksh88 and it -E doesn't work, any advice?

Comment: Try `find . -type f -name "*Log*" -print | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/"; } { $NF = ""; print; }' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name *.Log -print
```

This will give full path of all the files whose name ends with Log .

Comment: I only need directories where such files are present

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.Log' -print | sed 's,/[^/]*$,,' | sort -u`

Comment: beauty ! Works like a charm .

Answer (score 0):

> find . ( -type d ! -name . -prune ) -o -type d -name "*Log*"

```
tmp$ ls
App3LogDate.txt  App4LogDate.txt  folder1  folder2
tmp$ ls folder*
folder1:
App1LogDate.txt

folder2:
App2LogDate.txt
tmp$ find . \( -type d ! -name . -prune \) -o -type d -name "*Log*"
./folder2
./folder1
tmp$
```

Comment: current directory is missing

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU find (as Linux and many other modern Unixes do), you can just use the awesome printf operator and do this:

```
find -type f -name '*Log*' -printf '%h\n'
```

You probably also want to pipe that through a `sort -u` (or through `sort | uniq`, as appropriate).  Note that some commercial UNIX implementations will have that installed as gfind (or have a package that installs it as such).